# Returning values after mapping to set an attr in d3

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

After successfully calculating values for drawing several circles (cx attr), I cannot set cx value for svg element.

I already double checked that my React + D3 version (this one is in pure d3 for animation purposes) is returning the exact same values, so the problem isn't the calculation or value type.

```
d3.select(this.refs.dotsGroup)
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(this.state.lines)
  .attr("cx", d => {
    _.map(d.yearValArr, u => {
      const values = Object.values(u)

      const scaledValue = values[0].scaled

      return scaledValue
    })
  })
```

Any ideas in what is wrong with my return statement?

Comment: The callback provided to `.attr("cx", ...` doesn't return anything! It does call `_.map()`, the return value is discarded, though. Furthermore, returning the result of `_.map()` is correct either because a single value is expected, not an array.

Comment: @altocumulus in deed I had forgotten the return statement before the map. The _.map() is returning single values like the react version. I added the return before map but now I get "Error: <circle> attribute cx: Expected length, "426.901841317367…".". I get this for all circles in the group.

Comment: That is highly unlikely! I have never seen a `.map()` method returning a single value in whatsoever library. What is you `_` refering to: Underscore, lodash? Both return an array from their `.map()` methods. That would also explain the error message you witnessed.

Comment: @altocumulus yes you're right. These methods don't return single values. What would be your approach. Using a for loop, or something along those lines ? Or some d3 method ?

Comment: Depends largely on what you are actually trying to do. Setting up a [mcve] would make it much easier to help you out. There is more trouble ahead with your statement, though: After binding your data you are never appending any circle, i.e. you are not using the enter selection. This might be ok if all you are after is the update selection, however, I bet this was by accident... Again, try putting together some executable demo.

Comment: you don't see that becase this is included in a React project. The circles are in the DOM already. I think the problem is solved by nested selections. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27999963/d3-loop-array-inside-data-object

Comment: d3.select(this.refs.dotsGroup)
        .selectAll(".horizontal-data-group")
        .data(this.state.lines)
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(d => d.yearValArr)
        .attr("cx", d => {
          const values = Object.values(d)
          const scaledValue = values[0].scaled
          return scaledValue
        })



The problem was solved by using nested selection like I thought.@altocumulus the two problems you mentioned were correct , and with that help I reached the solution.How can I credit your help? Would you like to write an answer, so I can mark it correct?